# Can i get the reference to a class object from its variable

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

This is my class and i have a object of Geometry class a data varible

```
class Container 
{ 
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Geometry> Geom;
}
```

if i want to access the  Container object from the Geometry variable i can always form the geometry object with Container* as an argument.

```
Geometry( Container* cont);
Geometry(this);
```

is it possible for any data variable to return the base object if we dont explicitly define the base object ?

when i create a Container object

```
 Container cont;
 Geometry geom( &cont );
 cont.SetGeometry( geom );
```

now can i access the Container object from the geometry object which is a varible of Container object.

```
class Geometry()
{
    Container* rootContainer;
    Geometry( Container* cont) : rootContainer( cont ) { }
}
```

Comment: @Kaenbyou Rin  i have updated the question

Comment: I don't understand the last question and the last snippet. What represents the last snippet?

Comment: @Summit: "*if i want to access the Container object from the Geometry variable i can always form the geometry object with Container* as an argument.*" I don't understand this. There is no "Geometry variable"; there is at most a `Geom` variable, but the code you've given doesn't show how you get a `Container*` from that. Similarly, there is no "geometry object which is a varible of Container object"; there is a `shared_ptr<Geometry>`, but the `Geometry` pointer stored there is not a "variable of Container object".

Comment: @Nicol Bolas i have added the snippet for Geometry  class.

Comment: @Summit: So... what's your question? If `Geometry` stores a pointer to the `Container` that (presumably?) has shared ownership of it, then you can get a pointer to either object from the other object. So what problem are you having; just access the member if you want a pointer to the other object.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas could i do it without storing Container reference in Geometry object ?

Comment: @Summit: "*`cont.SetGeometry`*" Unless this function heap-allocates a new `Geometry`, then you're getting a `shared_ptr` to a stack variable. That's typically broken code.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas yes it does ,  Sum_Circle *sc = new Sum_Circle(*this); , return std::shared_ptr< Geometry >(sc);

Comment: I do not know about others, but I personally voted to close this because of the OP's insistence on using the ***wrong*** term 'base object' in the question, even after it was suggested that they should correct their terminology.  Questions must make sense.

Comment: @Mike Nakis no worries , thanks for your answer , though i am passing the base object pointer at the time object creation , just wanted to know if i can skip that step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this.  That's because C++ objects are quite lightweight and they do not carry extra unnecessary information.

Wanting to do this (without passing the contained object a pointer to its container) is indicative of a bad design.

Comment: It’s perhaps worth saying that this is utterly impossible only for the pointer case; turning a *direct* member and its containing class into a reference to the containing object is mathematically reasonable but considered undesirable for aliasing optimization analysis.

Comment: @DavisHerring yes, you must be referring to the `offsetof()` macro.  Still an ungodly hack if you ask me.  *If that path down you go, only pain will you find.*

Comment: It’s in fact undefined behavior in general to navigate **up** an object hierarchy via `offsetof` (and/or `reinterpret_cast`), because of the optimization I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your code and your compiler implementation.

If both `std::shared_ptr<T>` and your container are implemented as standard-layout types and the member is the first non-static data member of your container, then you can simply reinterpret_cast the pointer to your member to a pointer to the container:

```cpp
ptr_to_container = reinterpret_cast<Container*>(ptr_to_member);
```

and vice versa. (See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout#Notes)).

You cannot do this portably as compiler implementations vary. (The C++ standard never requires that all `shared_ptr` specializations be standard-layout.)

This can be, however, useful when interoping with C callbacks where a context pointer is not passed, as C structs are always standard layout.